# KeyUp event after TextBox is already updated

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, textbox, wpf-controls

Consider this basic `TextBox` in WPF:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" KeyUp="textBox1_KeyUp" />
```

And the event:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ Debug.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + "; " + e.Key.ToString()); }
```

If I type slow in the `TextBox` the output is:

```
t; T
te; E
tes; S
test; T
```

But if I type fast, the output is wrong (note the *S* already in `textBox1.Text` when processing key *E*):

```
t; T
tes; E
test; S
test; T
```

I want to process the correct `e.Key` (the last pressed). It seems to me that the event is not updated as fast as the `TextBox.Text` property. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see this behavior is because the contents of the `TextBox` are updated shortly after the `KeyDown` event occurs.  When typing very fast it's possible to do it in the following order

- KeyDown: T
- KeyUp: T
- KeyDown: E
- KeyDown: S
- KeyUp: E
- KeyUp: S

If you want to process the last key which was pressed down in the `KeyUp` event you would have to listen to `KeyDown` and store the value somewhere between the events.  I wouldn't recomend that though as you can get key events in many orders you wouldn't expect (especially on non-English keyboards).  I would stick with handling the event in `KeyDown` or `KeyUp`.